# JavaScript setTimeout alert order

Tags: javascript, settimeout, alert

```
function delay(time) {
    var date = new Date();
    while (new Date() - date < time) {};
}    
function a(n) {
    alert(n);
}
function c(n) {
    console.log(n);
}
setTimeout(()=>{a(1);}, 1000);
setTimeout(()=>{c(2);}, 3000);
setTimeout(()=>{c(3);}, 3000);
setTimeout(()=>{c(4);}, 3000);
setTimeout(()=>{c(5);}, 3000);
setTimeout(()=>{c(6);}, 3000);
```

When I use this code, the order of 2 ~ 6 is random.
Why "alert" make the browser do that?

---

I found that the Timer is delayed to put callbacks into callback queue when using "alert", not when using "delay". But I don't understand why it doesn't put callbacks in a specific order after finishing "alert"

---

I tryed this:

```
setTimeout(()=>{a(1);delay(3000)}, 1000);
setTimeout(()=>{c(2);}, 1000);
setTimeout(()=>{c(3);}, 1001);
setTimeout(()=>{c(4);}, 1002);
setTimeout(()=>{c(5);}, 1003);
setTimeout(()=>{c(6);}, 1004);
```

and result is:

```
5 3 4 6 2
```

---

if I do this:

```
setTimeout(()=>{c(1);delay(3000)}, 1000);
setTimeout(()=>{c(2);}, 1000);
setTimeout(()=>{c(3);}, 1000);
setTimeout(()=>{c(4);}, 1000);
setTimeout(()=>{c(5);}, 1000);
setTimeout(()=>{c(6);}, 1000);
```

the result is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I just wonder why alert blocking js makes different.

---

Well,the order is random only in chrome, not in IE or Firefox.

Comment: Probably becuase setTimout is not accurate and there is no magic queue.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the alert, it's the response time of console.log. 
Even they are scheduled sequentially nothing guarantees you that the execution ends in the same order. As they are fired all after 3 seconds (+ the time to running the next setTimeout instruction) the execution ends at another time, nothing to do with it start time.

You should add an offset for each *setTimeout* call to get more margin time to get the response in order.

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of the alert but because they all have same time delay and they are not ordered in a queue as you expect them to.

If you want to achieve that, then do:

```
function a(n) {
    alert(n);
}
function c(n) {
    console.log(n);
}
setTimeout(()=>{a(1);}, 1000);
setTimeout(()=>{
    c(2);
    c(3);
    c(4);
    c(5);
    c(6);
}, 3000);
```

and the order will be preserved.

Comment: But if I don't alert ( use "setTimeout(()=>{c(1);}, 1000);" ), the outputs are in the order 123456, even when I use "setTimeout(()=>{c(1);delay(3000)}, 1000);"

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your desired output. Please, type what you need your output to be like.